# How to create an array of objects with different values for each

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm new to programming.

I want to create an array of 4 objects with different values for each object, without overwriting the previous one.

This is my code:

```
$WKey = "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
$keys = get-childitem -path hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
$IN = @{}
foreach ($key in $keys.pschildname){

   $name = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name displayname
   if ($name -like '*injaz*'){
        $HM = @{}
        $HM.Name = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name displayname
        $HM.Version = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name displayVersion
        $HM.Uninstaller = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name UninstallString
        $HM.Keyname = $key
        $Objectname = New-Object PSobject -Property $HM
        $IN.add($Objectname.Name,$Objectname.Version,$Objectname.Uninstaller,$Objectname.keyname)
        $Objectname
        $IN
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a pscustom object and add the properties to it.

```
$WKey = "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
$keys = get-childitem -path hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
$IN = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@{}
foreach ($key in $keys.pschildname){

   $name = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name displayname
   if ($name -like '*injaz*'){
        #Create object
        $HM = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
        #Add properties to object 
        $HM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name displayname)
        $HM  | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Version" -Value $(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $WKey$key -name displayVersion)
        #Continue with the other values

        #Add object to array
        $IN.Add($HM) | Out-Null
   }
}
```